# How to create a Reactor Netty hot stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to find a way to create a hot stream where i could insert data in one method and a subscriber could get the data in another method.
I have succeeded using a `WorkQueueProcessor`, but I am not sure if this is the right way of doing that. Is it possible to do the same thing using Flux.create ?
Here's my working snippet:

1. Call `connect();`
2. Send byte data to server, the client will receive a response from `tcp` server and `workQueueProcessor` will emit the data.

   ```
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class TcpCli {

       @Setter
       private Connection connection;
       private NettyOutbound out;

       //Creation of Work Queue Processor, can a Flux.create here can do the same job ?
       private WorkQueueProcessor<String> workQueueProcessor = WorkQueueProcessor.<String>builder().build();
       public Mono<? extends Connection> connect() {
           return TcpClient.create()
               .host(tcpConfig.getHost())
               .port(tcpConfig.getPort())
               .handle(this::handleConnection)
               .connect();
       }
       public Mono<String> sendData(ByteArray data) {
           out.sendByteArray(Mono.just(data)).then().subscribe();

           //Get emitted data from workQueueProcessor
           return workQueueProcessor.next();
       }
       private Publisher<Void> handleConnection(NettyInbound in, NettyOutbound out) {
           this.out = out;
           in.receive().asString()
               .log("In received")
               .subscribe(str -> {
                   LOGGER.info(String.format("Inbound: %s", str));

                   //Emit data to workQueueProcessor
                   workQueueProcessor.onNext(str);
               });
           return out
               .neverComplete()    //keep connection alive
               .log("Never close");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple input sources and more than one subscribers, I think you are on right way.

If the NettyInbound is the only input source of your steam, then you don't need to use any Processors. Just subscribe to it.

If you have multiple input sources for your stream, and you have only one subscriber, in your case NettyOutbound, you may try 'UnicastProcessor' which is much light weighted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what the @Setter does here. I try the same code and it always gives the out

```
@Setter
private Connection connection;
private NettyOutbound out;
```

Comment: Sure, this is an annotation from project Lombok that adds a setter method for the property. So I don't need to write "public void setConnection(Connection) { this.connection = connection; }".

I suggest you watching the video at their website:
https://projectlombok.org/